# Understanding PostgreSQL & plpgsql defense against code injection

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-injection, plpgsql

On [this very useful page](http://bobby-tables.com/postgresql) there is this statement...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_access (p_uname TEXT)
  RETURNS timestamp LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
    SELECT accessed_at FROM users WHERE username = $1
$func$;
```

...as an explanation of how to be safe from SQL injection. I am trying to understand why i would be safe this way. What does PostgreSQL do for me, that keeps me safe? Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why is it safe?

PostgreSQL (and about any other DBMS) will first compile the statement with the `$1` in place, and only then will use the actual value provided by the user. So whatever is in the value cannot be interpreted as a part of the statement. In other words, using the parameter *separates code from data*.

#### Why do I need a procedure for this?

In most cases, you don't. What you really need is a mechanism that separates code from data, i.e. the parameter. In most languages and DB connectivity libraries nowadays there is a *parameterized query* support present, which allows you to write queries with placeholders (such as `?`) and provide data through a separate parameter.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful.